# Bind Repeater with JSON file strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Hello I am having a JSON file as follows

```
{
  "Employee1": {
    "Year1": {
      "StartRange": 22,
      "EndRange": 44
    },
    "Year2": {
      "StartRange": 24,
      "EndRange": 55
    }
  },
  "Employee2": {
    "Year1": {
      "StartRange": 29,
      "EndRange": 40
    },
    "Year2": {
      "StartRange": 44,
      "EndRange": 77
    }
  }
}
```

I want to read this JSON file and keep it in a List and Dispaly in a web page using Repeater control as follows(Refer Image)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5CPD.png)

I am having Textbox controls for Employee,Year,Start and End Range to add new values to the Repaeter when clicking a button.If I edit the details the updated JSOn string will be overridden in the JSOn file.How to do this in C#?

Comment: Create a class representing the JSON structure and (de)serialize into it.

Answer (score 0):

As CodeCaster said, create a class, it will look like this:

```
    public class Year
{
    public int StartRange { get; set; }
    public int EndRange { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public List<Year> Year { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Employee> Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Then use Newtonsoft Serializer, [here you find an example](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializingjson.htm).

Then you can bind it with a Repeater, if you want CRUD functions (create, update, delete) then use a GridView.

**Edit:**

**I created a runnable sample for you:**

**Data-Input:**

```js
       {
'Employee':[
  {
    'Year':[{
      'StartRange': 22,
      'EndRange': 44
    },
    {
      'StartRange': 24,
      'EndRange': 55
    }
]
  },
  {
    'Year':[{
      'StartRange': 29,
      'EndRange': 40
    },
     {
      'StartRange': 44,
      'EndRange': 77
    }
]
  }
]
}
```

**C# Deserialize**

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I would like to know how to create a list from a class structure you have written for my query.

Comment: Getting null value in RootObject after deserializing jSON string by your code

Comment: It depends on your input structure, the code works.
Employee1, Employee2 and Year1, and Year2 will cause problems because it won't be automaticly interpreted as an array.

I renamed that to Employee and Year (without the numbers), so I mean your data-structure is wrong. Better use Year: {Name:.. ; Start:...;End ...} instead of Year1, Year2, ...

Comment: If I have a Dictionary, How to bind dictionary data to repeater? Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, LabelData>> dd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, LabelData>>>(json);